# ¿Se puede hacer la siguiente actividad sin usar bucles?

Tags: java

***EJERCICIO:***

*Digitar un Numero Entero Positivo y dividirlo en 5 dígitos, EL Primer y Último Digito Se eleva al Cuadrado*.

Esta es una solución con diferentes métodos que no se me permiten usar, con bucles y la libreria `LinkedList`.

```
public static void actividad03() {

    int numerito = 0;
    Scanner teclado3= new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("ingrese un numero de 5 digitos");
    numerito = teclado3.nextInt();

        LinkedList<Integer> stack = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        while(numerito > 0){
            stack.push(numerito % 10);
            numerito = numerito / 10;
        }
        while ((!stack.isEmpty())){
            System.out.println(stack.pop());
}
}
```

Comment: ¿Has probado a utilizar `Math.pow()`? Es por así decirlo un método para elevar números a una potencia, su sintaxis es la siguiente:
Math.pow(numeroAPotenciar, potencia);

Comment: Se puede y es incluso más fácil, debes recibir un string y tratarlo como un array de char

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo pongo extenso por claridad. He entendido que no puedes usar bucles ni librerías linkedlist ni Math.

```
    public static void actividad03() {

    char n0,n1,n2,n3,n4;
    int intn0,intn1,intn2,intn3,intn4;
    System.out.println("ingrese un numero de 5 digitos\n");
    Scanner teclado= new Scanner (System.in);
    String numeritoStr = teclado.nextLine();
    n0=numeritoStr.charAt(0);
    n1=numeritoStr.charAt(1);
    n2=numeritoStr.charAt(2);
    n3=numeritoStr.charAt(3);
    n4=numeritoStr.charAt(4);
    intn0 = Character.getNumericValue(n0);
    intn1 = Character.getNumericValue(n1);
    intn2 = Character.getNumericValue(n2);
    intn3 = Character.getNumericValue(n3);
    intn4 = Character.getNumericValue(n4);              
    System.out.println("Dividido en 5 digitos = "+ intn0+" "+" "+intn1+" "+ intn2+" "+intn3+" "+intn4);
    intn0=intn0*intn0;
    intn4=intn4*intn4;
    System.out.println("Con primero y último al cuadrado = "+ intn0+" "+" "+intn1+" "+ intn2+" "+intn3+" "+intn4);
    

        
}
```

Comment: Hay diferencía entre su codigo y el original.  En el originial si el numero tiene menos de 5 digitos, el codgio funciona.  Pero su codigo va a fallar (por exemplo con 4 digitos, "n4=numeritoStr.charAt(4);"  va  a fallar).  También, si el ingreso no es un número, la respuesta de tu código va estar "interesante"